# LIRC doesn't work in my RaspberryPi 3

Tags: pi-3, lirc

I have a KEYES remote, and I tried to connect it with my RaspberryPi[image]

[image]

I used the following connection with Raspberry PI GPIOs:

```
GND -> PIN 6
3.3V -> PIN 1
OUT -> PIN 12
```

I installed LIRC using the command :

```
sudo apt-get install lirc
```

I updated the file `/boot/config.txt` by uncommenting the line "dtoverlay=lirc-rpi" and I added following lines:

```
dtparam=gpio_in_pin=18

dtparam=gpio_out_pin=17
```

Then I rebooted my Raspberry PI by executing the command:

```
sudo reboot
```

After rebooting, I executed the following commands:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lirc stop
mode2 -d /dev/lirc0
```

But nothing is happening when I press a key on the remote.
Is there anything I should do to make the remote work?

Answer (score 1):

It's confusing because LIRC and the configurations have changed during the switch from Jessie(Debian 8) based systems to Stretch(Debian 9) systems.

### What system are you using?

First off, you need to find out what's your system.

Execute the following command to find out what system(Debian 8 or 9) is currently running on your Pi.

### A Recommendation

Just as a recommendation, I suggest removing and then reinstalling LIRC.

In my case, LIRC seemed to be installed at first but some of the configuration files, `mode2`, and `irrecord` were nowhere to be found.

This may not be your case but be aware just in case.

### Debian 8

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get remove lirc`
3. `sudo apt-get install lirc`
4. `sudo vim /boot/config.txt`

   - add/uncomment this line to be exactly like this: `dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_out_pin=18`
5. `sudo vim /etc/lirc/hardware.conf`

   - edit the `DRIVER` value as `DRIVER="default"`
   - edit the `DEVICE` value as `DEVICE="/dev/lirc0"`
6. `sudo reboot`
7. `lsmod | grep lirc`

   - there should be 2 or 3 lines about LIRC,
8. `ls /dev`

   - `lirc0` should be present,
9. `sudo service lirc stop`
10. `mode2 -d /dev/lirc0`

And finally, you can test your IR receiver with the buttons on your remote.

### Debian 9

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get remove lirc`
3. `sudo apt-get install lirc`
4. `sudo vim /boot/config.txt`

   - add/uncomment this line to be exactly like this: `dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_out_pin=18`
5. `sudo vim /etc/lirc/hardware.conf`

   - edit the `DRIVER` value as `DRIVER="default"`
   - edit the `DEVICE` value as `DEVICE="/dev/lirc0"`
6. `sudo mv /etc/lirc/lircd.conf.d/devinput.lircd.conf /etc/lirc/lircd.conf.d/devinput.lircd.dist`
7. `sudo reboot`
8. `lsmod | grep lirc`

   - there should be 2 or 3 lines about LIRC,
9. `ls /dev`,

   - `lirc0` should be present,
10. `sudo systemctl stop lircd.service`
11. `sudo systemctl stop lircd.socket`
12. `mode2 -d /dev/lirc0`

And finally, you can test your IR receiver with the buttons on your remote.

### Still Not Working

If it's still not working, there are a few things for troubleshooting:

1. check your circuitry with another remote just to rule out it wasn't the first remote or its dead batteries,
2. check your IR receivers power source; most tutorials plug it into 3V and your IR receiver could be fine with that but it could also work with 5V and require it to be 5V in your circuit design,
3. If you have an LED around and some basic circuitry elements, [you can easily construct](https://www.modmypi.com/blog/raspberry-pis-remotes-ir-receivers) a simple circuit where the LED blink once your IR receiver receives something.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately, it didn't worked

Answer (score -1):

Think you forgot the gpio_in_pin for the dtoverlay line...cheeers